# How can I create a Book List using ES6 Classes and Objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Tasks :

1. HTML - Create the structure of the page (Hint: the book list could be a table, and any new added book on the JS side could be an  element).
2. CSS - style the elements to look like in the attached gif
3. JS :

- Create 2 classes with corespondent constructors(class Book and class UI)
- Book class( used for creating book objects)
- UI class( methods only here: for add the book to the list, delete the book, validate the input show confirmation message boxes)

Note: Use arrow functions as much as possible when needed.

Gif :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kaxo.jpg

my code :

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Book List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-3">
                    <h4>Add Book</h4>
                    <form id="form" action="#">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title">Title</label>
                            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="author">Author</label>
                            <input type="text" name="author" id="author" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="isbn">ISBN#</label>
                            <input type="text" name="isbn" id="isbn" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <table id="table" class="table">
                        <thead id="thead">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                                <th scope="col">Author</th>
                                <th scope="col">ISBN#</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tbody">
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
// get html elements
const formElem = document.getElementById('form');
const titleElem = document.getElementById('title');
const authorElem = document.getElementById('author');
const isbnElem = document.getElementById('isbn');

// console.log(formElem, titleElem, authorElem, isbnElem);

class Book {

}

class UI {
    constructor(){

    }

    addBookToList(){

    }

    deleteBook(){

    }
}

formElem.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let ui = new UI();
});
```

The es6 part, I didn't manage to learn it and I have no idea how I should proceed, any suggestion is welcome, thanks..

Comment: What have you tried ? I do not try to be disrespectful, but we don't do homework. At least try to do it or show what u have done

Comment: Here is a working version https://codepen.io/riza-khan/pen/oNwxyNM?editors=1011

The only issue is that it doesn't follow you guidlines exactly. Are those hard rules or nice to haves?

Comment: After a little bit of consideration, using classes for the UI is a bit overkill. Storing all the data in a array in Javascript is so much cleaner...

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take to read the code, I didn't understand exactly, that's why I didn't even try ..